# Laravel 5.1 S3 Secure Image access via Restful API

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5.1

I am using token based auth for a Restful API on Laravel 5.1.  I am using S3 as the file storage to upload user specific images.  I would like to limit the access only to the user who has uploaded the image(s).   They should be able to view the images in a mobile API.  Is there are a way to do that with Laravel 5.1 and S3 without making the S3 directory public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to do that directly with the requester and S3, but you can incorporate the S3 client SDK into your Laravel project which acts as the middleman.

Your Laravel project will have an API which can receive requests to fetch the resource and it will need to do the authentication and authorization.
This will also require a mapping from the user_ids to a list of URLs/names of the resources that user has access to. Something like DynamoDB is fine.

If successful, you could do one of two things:

1. Fetch the object and return it directly to the requester, this is probably the most secure and easiest.
2. Get a Signed URL (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), such that the requester then can fetch the resource separately. This is useful for large objects such as videos, but anyone who has access to the URL in the middle such as proxy servers could also have access to the resource.